# Access Hyperledger Indy Node deployed in virtual machine using local workstation

Tags: python, docker, ip, nat, hyperledger-indy

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/main/docs/how-tos/write-did-and-query-verkey/README.md) and I have a virtual machine running an Indy pool (ip: 192.168.15.177 internal net: 10.217.0.18). It is a simple docker command to run the pool in the VM:

```
docker build -f ci/indy-pool.dockerfile -t indy_pool .
docker run -itd -p 9701-9708:9701-9708 indy_pool
```

In my local workstation, I try to run the code present in the link `write_did.py`, which call a functions to access the pool with the genesis transactions and it has the pool_ip:

```
def pool_genesis_txn_data():
    pool_ip = environ.get("TEST_POOL_IP", "192.168.15.177")
    
    return "\n".join([
        # Gen transactions
    ])
```

But after a moment, I get a `PoolLedgerTimeout` error, which is described as:

> Make sure that the pool of local nodes in Docker is running on the
> same ip/ports as in the docker_pool_transactions_genesis (for further
> details see [How to start local nodes pool with docker](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/README.md#how-to-start-local-nodes-pool-with-docker))

I wonder how the access the virtual machine since the router translates the ip: 192.168.15.177 to the internal net: 10.217.0.18. Looking at the documentation, I didn't find anything similar to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My docker container is running at:

[my docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTU7O.png)

Lets look for the genesis.txn file:

[code i ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTLAd.png)

```
docker exec -it indy_pool /bin/bash

cd var/lib/indy/sandbox
```

in this folder you have genesis.txn you can run:

```
less pool_transactions_genesis
```

and get the genesis.txn (note that every ip address is 127.0.0.1 for nodes and clients so i would have to set my TEST_POOL_IP as 127.0.0.1):

[My genesis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oLiC.png)

```
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node1","blskey":"4N8aUNHSgjQVgkpm8nhNEfDf6txHznoYREg9kirmJrkivgL4oSEimFF6nsQ6M41QvhM2Z33nves5vfSn9n1UwNFJBYtWVnHYMATn76vLuL3zU88KyeAYcHfsih3He6UHcXDxcaecHVz6jhCYz1P2UZn2bDVruL5wXpehgBfBaLKm3Ba","blskey_pop":"RahHYiCvoNCtPTrVtP7nMC5eTYrsUA8WjXbdhNc8debh1agE9bGiJxWBXYNFbnJXoXhWFMvyqhqhRoq737YQemH5ik9oL7R4NTTCz2LEZhkgLJzB3QRQqJyBNyv7acbdHrAT8nQ9UkLbaVL9NBpnWXBTw4LEMePaSHEw66RzPNdAX1","client_ip":"127.0.0.1","client_port":9702,"node_ip":"127.0.0.1","node_port":9701,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"Gw6pDLhcBcoQesN72qfotTgFa7cbuqZpkX3Xo6pLhPhv"},"metadata":{"from":"Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":1,"txnId":"fea82e10e894419fe2bea7d96296a6d46f50f93f9eeda954ec461b2ed2950b62"},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node2","blskey":"37rAPpXVoxzKhz7d9gkUe52XuXryuLXoM6P6LbWDB7LSbG62Lsb33sfG7zqS8TK1MXwuCHj1FKNzVpsnafmqLG1vXN88rt38mNFs9TENzm4QHdBzsvCuoBnPH7rpYYDo9DZNJePaDvRvqJKByCabubJz3XXKbEeshzpz4Ma5QYpJqjk","blskey_pop":"Qr658mWZ2YC8JXGXwMDQTzuZCWF7NK9EwxphGmcBvCh6ybUuLxbG65nsX4JvD4SPNtkJ2w9ug1yLTj6fgmuDg41TgECXjLCij3RMsV8CwewBVgVN67wsA45DFWvqvLtu4rjNnE9JbdFTc1Z4WCPA3Xan44K1HoHAq9EVeaRYs8zoF5","client_ip":"127.0.0.1","client_port":9704,"node_ip":"127.0.0.1","node_port":9703,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"8ECVSk179mjsjKRLWiQtssMLgp6EPhWXtaYyStWPSGAb"},"metadata":{"from":"EbP4aYNeTHL6q385GuVpRV"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":2,"txnId":"1ac8aece2a18ced660fef8694b61aac3af08ba875ce3026a160acbc3a3af35fc"},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node3","blskey":"3WFpdbg7C5cnLYZwFZevJqhubkFALBfCBBok15GdrKMUhUjGsk3jV6QKj6MZgEubF7oqCafxNdkm7eswgA4sdKTRc82tLGzZBd6vNqU8dupzup6uYUf32KTHTPQbuUM8Yk4QFXjEf2Usu2TJcNkdgpyeUSX42u5LqdDDpNSWUK5deC5","blskey_pop":"QwDeb2CkNSx6r8QC8vGQK3GRv7Yndn84TGNijX8YXHPiagXajyfTjoR87rXUu4G4QLk2cF8NNyqWiYMus1623dELWwx57rLCFqGh7N4ZRbGDRP4fnVcaKg1BcUxQ866Ven4gw8y4N56S5HzxXNBZtLYmhGHvDtk6PFkFwCvxYrNYjh","client_ip":"127.0.0.1","client_port":9706,"node_ip":"127.0.0.1","node_port":9705,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"DKVxG2fXXTU8yT5N7hGEbXB3dfdAnYv1JczDUHpmDxya"},"metadata":{"from":"4cU41vWW82ArfxJxHkzXPG"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":3,"txnId":"7e9f355dffa78ed24668f0e0e369fd8c224076571c51e2ea8be5f26479edebe4"},"ver":"1"}
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node4","blskey":"2zN3bHM1m4rLz54MJHYSwvqzPchYp8jkHswveCLAEJVcX6Mm1wHQD1SkPYMzUDTZvWvhuE6VNAkK3KxVeEmsanSmvjVkReDeBEMxeDaayjcZjFGPydyey1qxBHmTvAnBKoPydvuTAqx5f7YNNRAdeLmUi99gERUU7TD8KfAa6MpQ9bw","blskey_pop":"RPLagxaR5xdimFzwmzYnz4ZhWtYQEj8iR5ZU53T2gitPCyCHQneUn2Huc4oeLd2B2HzkGnjAff4hWTJT6C7qHYB1Mv2wU5iHHGFWkhnTX9WsEAbunJCV2qcaXScKj4tTfvdDKfLiVuU2av6hbsMztirRze7LvYBkRHV3tGwyCptsrP","client_ip":"127.0.0.1","client_port":9708,"node_ip":"127.0.0.1","node_port":9707,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"4PS3EDQ3dW1tci1Bp6543CfuuebjFrg36kLAUcskGfaA"},"metadata":{"from":"TWwCRQRZ2ZHMJFn9TzLp7W"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":4,"txnId":"aa5e817d7cc626170eca175822029339a444eb0ee8f0bd20d3b0b76e566fb008"},"ver":"1"}
```

If you want to check the ledger connection from your local machine you can use indy-cli, this is good if you want to know the problem is not with the ledger but the python code.

indy-cli command to check out if your local machine is connected to the ledger (through docker):

```
pool create newPool gen_txn_file=YOUR_GENTXN_FILEPATH
pool connect newPool
```

if you see this as the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shk3v.png),
then you have successfully connected to the ledger from your local machine.

So your pool_ip parameter might be wrong, also the `"\n".join()` part requires the genesis file inside join statement as seen in [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/main/docs/how-tos/write-did-and-query-verkey/python/utils.py)

But if i were you i would first check if the connection is possible from the [indy-cli](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/main/cli/README.md) to see if the pool is created properly.